# Word palindrome in C

Tags: c, text, spaces, words

My task is to find word palindromes in a text file and to NOT print them into results file. The results file should only contain all the spaces and words that are NOT palindromes. I've been working on this program for two solid weeks, but as I am a total newb in C, I can't simply imagine how to do this correctly. Also, I have to work in Linux environent, so I can't use commands like strrev() which would make my life a lot easier at this point...

Anyways, data file contains a lot of words in a lot of lines separated by quite a few spaces.

Here is the program that is working, but doesn't work with any spaces, because I don't know how to check them at the needed place.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

const int CMAX  = 1000;
const int Dydis = 256;
FILE *dataFile;
FILE *resFile;

void palindrome(char *linex);

int main(){
    char duom[CMAX], res[CMAX], linex[Dydis];

    printf("What's the name of data file? \n");
    scanf("%s", duom);
    dataFile=fopen(duom, "r");
    if (dataFile==NULL){
        printf ("Error opening data file \n");
        return 0;
    };

    printf("What's the name of results file? \n");
    scanf ("%s", res);
    resFile=fopen(res, "w");
    if (resFile==NULL){
        printf ("Error opening results file \n");
        return 0;
    };

    while (fgets(linex, sizeof(linex), dataFile)) {
        palindrome(linex);
    }
    printf ("all done!");
    fclose(dataFile);
    fclose(resFile);
}

void palindrome(char *linex){
    int i, wordlenght, j;
    j = 0;
    char *wordie;
    const char space[2] = " ";
    wordie = strtok(linex, space);
    while ( wordie != NULL ) {
        wordlenght = strlen(wordie);
        if (wordie[j] == wordie[wordlenght-1]) {
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(wordie); i++) {
                if (wordie[i] == wordie[wordlenght-1]) {
                    if (i == strlen(wordie)-1) {
                        fprintf(resFile,"");
                    }
                    wordlenght--;
                }
                else {
                    fprintf(resFile,"%s", wordie);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf(resFile,"%s", wordie);
        }

        wordie = strtok(NULL, space);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean palindrome, right?

Comment: What is a polyndrome?

Comment: I was just about to react the same way... how is it possible to make a program on a thing you can't even write :p

Comment: your palindrome function is overly complicated... why not just use a function palindrome with a loop that verify that word[i]=word[lenght-i-1] ??

Comment: What exactly is the input supposed to look like? One word per line?

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language, made a mistake. Input may be : a lot of spaces, then a word, a lot of spaces again and maybe a few other words separated by spaces too. On another line it may differ, but the main thought is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Code below works as following:

- input file is read char by char
- if char read isn't alphanumeric, then it is written to the output file
- else, the whole word is read with `fscanf`
- if word is not a palindrome, then write to the output file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_pal(char* word) {
    size_t len = strlen(word);
    char* begin = word;
    char* end = word + len - 1;
    if (len == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    while (begin <= end) {
        if (*begin != *end) {
            return 0;
        }
        begin++;
        end--;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fin = fopen("pals.txt", "r");
    if (fin == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE* fout = fopen("out_pals.txt", "w");
    if (fout == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }
    int ret;
    char word[100];
    while ((ret = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) {
        if (!isalpha(ret)) {
            fprintf(fout, "%c", ret);
        }
        else {
            ungetc(ret, fin);
            fscanf(fin, "%s", word);
            if (!is_pal(word)) {
                fprintf(fout, "%s", word);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

I've created file with following content:

```
cancer kajak anna sam truck
test1   abc   abdcgf  groove   void
xyz annabelle  ponton  belowoleb   thing
cooc  ringnir
```

The output file :

```
cancer   sam truck
test1   abc   abdcgf  groove   void
xyz annabelle  ponton     thing
(line with two spaces)
```

As you can see, the number of spaces between words are the same as in the input file.

I've assumed that single word could have 100 chars maximum. If there would be longer words, reading with `fscanf` onto fixed-size buffer can be harmful.

Comment: You forgot to loop over the word. This is only checking the outermost characters.

Comment: Gosh... what a fail :) thanks for noticing it, fixed.

Comment: It's very good code, but what about the spaces in input file? Because they also need to appear at the same exact place in output file as they are in input file. Maybe I need to check with fgetc() before and after giving the "word" to procedure?

Comment: That wouldn't work. My solution simply discards all the newlines and spaces. Am I correct with statement that when word is a palindrome it could be replaced by an empty string?

Comment: @macfij THANK YOU SO MUCH! You just saved my life, I've been trying to work out this program for far too long...

Comment: I'm glad that i could help you. Make sure that you know what each used function in code do. Also, if this was helpful, you can mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- `strtok()` gives you a pointer to the start of delimited words but it does not
  extract them or put them in their own string for you.
- You need some logic to find the end of each word. The function
  `strlen()` will tell you how many characters there are from the char*
  that it gets until a null-character. If you give it a pointer to the start
  of a word within a sentence it will give you the length from the start of the
  word to the end of the sentence.
- Breaking `palindrome()` into a function that loops over words in a line and a
  function that returns whether or not a single word is a palindrome
  may help.
- Your for loop is checking each pair of letters twice. `i` only needs to scan over half
  of the word length.
- You only need a single `if` within `palindrome()`. I'm not sure why you have so many.
  They're redundant.